# How to check if property[] has been used

Tags: c#, nsubstitute

I use Vs2015 with NSubstitute 3.1.0.
This code is passed but shouldn't.

```
public class Test
{
    public string[] Content { get; set; }
}
[Fact]
public void Should_What()
{
    var obj = Substitute.For<Test>();
    var test = obj.DidNotReceive().Content;
    var test2 = obj.Received().Content;
}
```

If replace class `Test` to interface it will works well, but in my test I have class.

How to check  if property Content has been used ?

Comment: Test the value of the `Content` property to see if it's still assigned its default value, and there's no need to use a substitute if you're going to be using the class directly.

Comment: Side note: Please do not name classes using interface naming ("IXxxxx") in public samples - I've edited the post to make it less confusing.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov the text still says "class ITest". That's not correct now?

Comment: @Julian thanks - fixed.

Comment: Hi Kamil, if you are substituting for a class please make sure the members are `virtual`. See [Substituting for classes](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/creating-a-substitute/#substituting-infrequently-and-carefully-for-classes) and [How NSubstitute works](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/how-nsub-works/) for more information. Installing [NSubstitute.Analyzers](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/nsubstitute-analysers/) can help detect problems like this and suggest fixes.

Comment: @DavidTchepak thanks for the link [Substituting for classes](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/creating-a-substitute/#substituting-infrequently-and-carefully-for-classes), it explains how it works. But, in my opinion its a bug.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use virtual for the property.

```
public virtual string[] Content { get; set; }
```

But, if two opposing tests return the True at the same time, we have a bug.
Can explain why and indicate a solution, but this is a workaround.

In my opinion it should throw an exception (ex. NotSupportedException, when a test is executed on non-virtual properties).
The testing environment is expected to detect the problems. So it should be pessimistic.
In this case should be better to return false instead of true. To sign the developer the problem (even if it is in the framework).
For example in SQL when try to check null value, will always return false (null == true, null == 0 or even null == null).
This is just my point.
What do you guys think about it?

Comment: [NSubstitute.Analyzers](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/nsubstitute-analysers/) will prevent this test from compiling, which prevents this bug. The C# or VB analysers should be installed whenever you install the NSubstitute package. Hope this helps.